# Multiline regex pattern java

Tags: java, regex

I have a multi line string:

**"Line 1 \n Line 2 \n Line 3"**

What will be the regex pattern which will produce:

**Line 1**

**Line 2**

**Line 3**

I am using the pattern : **(?m)^.*$**

I am using **.find()** method of **Matcher** class in following manner:

```
while(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: please show what you have tried? and explain your question a bit more

Comment: Regex doesn't produce anything, but is searching for patterns. How you will use its result is other thing. You can for instance try to find `.*` and it will find each line, as long `.` doesn't match line separators (which is default behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Since dot in the regex by default won't match any newline characters , you could consider adding DOTALL MODIFIER.

```
"(?s).*"
```

OR

```
"[\\s\\S]*"
```